# "To be" is used as the infinitive: "He be like...", "Work be hard",

Tags: colloquial-language

I often see, of course, in colloquial contects, that the word "be" is used like "is" or "are" and so on.

E.g.: "I be very happy then", "School be like...", "You be hating on them"

---

But is it really the same meaning as if you'd replace it with "is"/"are",... ?

So translated would be: "I am very happy then", "School is like...", "You are hating on them"

Or is there a different meaning of that?

Comment: No difference in meaning, merely the correct form of the verb.  We are dealing with non-standard (colloquial) (idiomatic) vernacular here so don't be too keen to find rhyme or reason.

Comment: Some dialects feature the [habitual be](https://slate.com/human-interest/2015/06/the-habitual-be-why-cookie-monster-be-eating-cookies-whether-he-is-eating-cookies-or-not.html), where **be** is used to describe recurring or continuing actions.